# What is a cluster in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb

I am someone new to mongoDB and has absolutely no knowledge regarding databases so would like to know what is a cluster in MongoDB and what is the point of connecting to one in MongoDB? Is it a must to connect to one or can we just connect to the localhost?

Answer (score 93, accepted):

A mongodb cluster is the word usually used for **sharded cluster** in mongodb. The main purposes of a sharded mongodb are:

- Scale reads and writes along several nodes
- Each node does not handle the whole data so you can separate data along all the nodes of the shard. Each node is a member of a shard (which is a replicaset, see below for the explanation) and the data are separated on all shards.

This is the representation of a mongodb sharded cluster from the official [doc](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.0/core/sharding-introduction/).

[image: mongodb sharded cluster]

**If you are starting with mongodb, I do not recommend you to shard your data**. Shards are way more complicated to maintain and handle than replicasets are.
You should have a look at a basic replicaset. It is fault tolerant and sufficient for simple needs.

The ideas of a replicaset are :

- Every data are repartited on each node
- Only one node accept writes

A replicaset representation from the official [doc](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.0/core/replication-introduction/)

[image]

For simple apps **there is no problem to have your mongodb cluster on the same host than your application**. You can even have them on a single member replicaset but you won't be fault tolerant anymore.

Comment: Well said but a cluster need not always be sharded. You may very have production setups to have high availability with "just" bunch of read replicas with an internal quorum.

Comment: "Scale reads and writes along several nodes" -- this makes no sense to me, coming from a JavaScript background (haven't worked with MongoDB before). I would suggest a clearer explanation for this part.

Answer (score 11):

> Atlas-managed MongoDB deployments, or “clusters,” can be either a
> **replica set** or a **sharded cluster**.
>
> **replica set**: a cluster of MongoDB servers that implements replication and automated failover. (*Failover is a method of protecting computer systems from failure, in
> which standby equipment automatically takes over when the main system
> fails*.)
>
> – *replication*: a feature allowing multiple database servers to share the same data, thereby ensuring redundancy and facilitating load balancing. (*Redundancy is a system design in which a component is duplicated so if it fails there will be a backup*.)
>
> **sharded cluster**: the set of nodes comprising a sharded MongoDB deployment. A sharded cluster consists of config servers, shards, and
> one or more mongos routing processes.
>
> – *sharding*: a method for distributing data across multiple machines.
>
> A sharded cluster consists of ten servers: one server for the mongos [interface between the client applications and the sharded cluster] and three servers each for the first replica set, the second replica set, and the config server replica set
>
> – *shard*: a single mongod instance or replica set that stores some
> portion of a sharded cluster’s total data set. In production, all
> shards should be replica sets.

Sources: MongoDB docs: [Glossary](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/glossary/), [Create a Cluster](https://docs.atlas.mongodb.com/create-new-cluster/), [Convert a Replica Set to a Sharded Cluster](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/convert-replica-set-to-replicated-shard-cluster)

Answer (score -9):

It will be more clear, if you create a cluster in the [cloud website](https://cloud.mongodb.com) of mongo. Try free version. You can see live monitoring of servers.[image]

Comment: This is not related to the question by any means .